# Git "ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied" when using public keys

Tags: linux, security, git, gitosis, public-key-encryption

I have setup a git server using gitosis and everything was going fine. I decided to switch to using public keys for security reasons. I generated my key on my computer using this command.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "email@address.com"
```

I then added the public key to the keydir and included the key in my gitosis.conf file. I committed the changes and uploaded them to the server. When I tried to pull the changes in my git repo it gave me this error.

**Error**

```
sfa-e1505-dn:VIIAD stefanbossbaly$ git pull
DEBUG:gitosis.serve.main:Got command "git-upload-pack 'git/VIIAD.git'"
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'mac' as 'writable' on 'git/VIIAD.git'...
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Stripping .git suffix from 'git/VIIAD.git', new value 'git/VIIAD'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'app-dev'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'test'
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'mac' as 'writeable' on 'git/VIIAD.git'...
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Stripping .git suffix from 'git/VIIAD.git', new value 'git/VIIAD'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'app-dev'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'test'
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Access check for 'mac' as 'readonly' on 'git/VIIAD.git'...
DEBUG:gitosis.access.haveAccess:Stripping .git suffix from 'git/VIIAD.git', new value 'git/VIIAD'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'app-dev'
DEBUG:gitosis.group.getMembership:found 'mac' in 'test'
ERROR:gitosis.serve.main:Repository read access denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**gitosis.conf**

```
[gitosis]

loglevel = DEBUG

[group app-dev]
writable = VIIAD android-backend
members = home mac

[group test]
writable = test
members = home mac

[group gitosis-admin]
members = home
writable = gitosis-admin mac
```

Notice that I already have a key "home" and it is working fine. The "mac" key is giving me problems. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect using `ssh -vvvv yourgitserver` to see what key is getting served up. You can control which key is given and make aliases for your server to give different keys to the same machine via the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Hope this helps.

As an aside, use gitolite instead. It's actively developed and maintained; gitosis is not.

Comment: I will install gitolite and see if it works! If it does I will mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help!